# First rendering props retained if the vdom returned is exactly the same

Tags: preact

I have a very large object that gets passed around class and functional components. If the object is changed, the rerendering was causing usage of double the memory. At first I thought it was related to the object getting retained in the prevProps and that's how I asked this question.

On further investigation, I notice that the prevProps do get cleared and only the first rendering props are retained when the returned VDOM is always the same.

In the below code if I return a random number in the VDOM, I see only one TestObject object in the Memory. But if I return the simple Hello div that is always the same, I see two TestObject objects in memory, the very first one and the most recent one.

Is this likely a bug with preact or what is needed to fix this double memory issue?

```
const html = htm.bind(preact.h);
class TestObject {
    arr;
    constructor() {
        this.arr = Array(100000).fill({});
        this.arr[0] = Math.random();
    }
}
class TestRenderer extends preact.Component {
    render({ obj }) {
        return html`<div>Hello</div>`;
        // return html`<div>Hello ${Math.random()}</div>`;
    }
}
document.getElementById('render').onclick = () => {
    preact.render(html`<${TestRenderer} obj=${new TestObject()}/>`,document.getElementById('app'));
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by using 'htm/mini'. 'htm' by itself does some kind of caching which is avoided with 'htm/mini'. Not having caching might effect in other ways but for my app having to use twice the memory is not acceptable.